# Exec dynamic SQL query is not working on linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, linked-server

I want to insert data to the linked server table using dynamic SQL. For example:-

```sql
Declare @SqlCode nvarchar(max);
Set @SqlCode = 'Insert into [linked server].[Linked Server db].schema.tablename (column1,column2....) Select column1,column2.... from [source db].schema.tablename'
EXEC(@SqlCode)
```

The above code works fine when I run the code directly into the ssms query window and records are getting inserted. However, when I call this part of code through a procedure, The stored procedure is getting executed successfully but no records are getting inserted.

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the code/ process. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

I tried inserting the data to the same server table and it is getting inserted however I am facing the issue while loading it into the Linked Server.

Comment: Why are you using a deferred statement at all here, when there's nothing dynamic about the query.

Comment: Please test this linked server

Comment: Please Test https://thomaslarock.com/2016/03/sql-server-linked-server-connection-test/

Comment: post exact code of procedure. there should be no difference, unless you're running with different users or code is different

Comment: I'm guessing you have some params which are NULL so the dynamic SQL code becomes NULL as well